# Error while importing font OpenSanSrc, fontWeight 400 in react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I had a problem when importing font, it returned an error: *Unhandled Rejection (Error): Could not resolve font for undefined, fontWeight 400*.

```
import OpenSanSrc from 'assets/font/OpenSans-Regular.ttf';
Font.register({
 family: 'Open Sans',
 src: OpenSanSrc,
})
```

and applied style to the page like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    paddingVertical: 45,
    paddingHorizontal: 35,
    backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4',
    fontFamily: 'Open Sans'
  },
}
```

Does anyone have idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by keeping the font weight consistent when I register the font and when I use the font. I have a folder with many font files and an array to keep track of them. I go through each font and register a normal and bold version of it like -

```
allFontFamilies.forEach((fontFamily) => {
  Font.register({
    family: fontFamily,
    fonts: [
      {
        src: `/fonts/${fontFamily}-Regular.ttf`,
        fontWeight: 400,
      },
      {
        src: `/fonts/${fontFamily}-Bold.ttf`,
        fontWeight: 700,
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

To use this I do -

```
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionHeader: {
    fontWeight: 700,
    letterSpacing: "0.3pt",
    fontFamily: DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY,
  },
  pdfText: {
    fontFamily: DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY,
    color: DEFAULT_FONT_COLOR,
    fontWeight: 400,
  },
});
```